# missing dispform.aspx and editform.aspx on list

Tags: 2010, administration

I am getting a 404 webpage not found error when I try to get to a list in sharepoint. When I look in Sharepoint designer I notice that the dispform and editform.aspx forms are missing. Is there a way to restore these? When I try to add a new one I get an error message that the form already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try deleting them before adding the replacement pages? If not try that. If you can't find them in SharePoint Designer open your page in [SharePoint Manager 2010](http://spm.codeplex.com/releases/view/51438) and try to delete them in there.

Something else you could try is deleting the List and creating a new one. If you can't just delete it because of its content [create a ListTemplate](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/copy-or-move-a-list-by-using-a-list-template-HA101782479.aspx) (that includes the list's content) from that list before you delete it and restore it afterwards from your template.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking for them via "All Files" (look in the Navigation pane under Site Objects: All Files -> Lists? If you see them there then it's possible they were customized and the customizations somehow broke SP's ability to recognize them as List Item forms.